# How increase the /usr on freebsd 8.1?

Tags: freebsd

My guest vm running os freebsd 8.1 and today my /usr is full, and how to increase the /usr from another virtual disk.

ran df command

```
Filesystem  1K-blocks     Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/da0s1a   1012974   175918  756020    19%    /
devfs               1        1       0   100%    /dev
/dev/da0s1e   2026030   127744 1736204     7%    /tmp
/dev/da0s1f  25384812 23038656  315372    99%    /usr
/dev/da0s1d  20308398 10831484 7852244    58%    /var
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must get informations about usr partition:

- `du -s /usr/* | sort -n`

For example, you have another partition **/usr2** and big subdirectory **/usr/local** (very big on my system)

And you may (very ugly way):

- move /usr/local subdirectory on /usr2 and link it: `tar -C /usr -cf - local | tar -C /usr2 -xf - && mv /usr/local /usr/local2 && ln -s /usr2/local /usr && rm -rf /usr/local2`
- copy all data from usr to usr2 (`tar -C /usr -cf - . | tar -C /usr2 -xf -`) and change mountpoint on /etc/fstab

If you do not have a big place, you may use first method for subsubdirectory.

For your situation you may:

- create subdir in var: `mkdir /var/usr/`
- and use above method with /var/usr instead of /usr2